# Mongodb - Mongoimport error invalid character

Tags: mongodb

I tried to import a simple json file using mongoimport and i get the following error

```
PER-MacBook-Pro:/AJ$ mongoimport --db test --collection samplePM --file /users/AJ/Documents/Development/ETLwork/Dummydata/Penguin_Players.json
2015-06-16T09:53:57.291-0400    connected to: localhost
2015-06-16T09:53:57.293-0400    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '\\' looking for beginning of object key string
2015-06-16T09:53:57.293-0400    imported 0 documents
```

Sample json file is as follows:

```
      {  
         "position":"Right Wing",
         "id":8465166,
         "weight":200,
         "height":"6' 0\"",
         "imageUrl":"http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8465166.jpg",
         "birthplace":"Seria, BRN",
         "age":37,
         "name":"Craig Adams",
         "birthdate":"April 26, 1977",
         "number":27
      },
      {  
         "position":"Right Wing",
         "id":8475761,
         "weight":195,
         "height":"6' 2\"",
         "imageUrl":"http://1.cdn.nhle.com/photos/mugs/8475761.jpg",
         "birthplace":"Gardena, CA, USA",
         "age":23,
         "name":"Beau Bennett",
         "birthdate":"November 27, 1991",
         "number":19
      }
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Seems you have non "UTF-8" characters in there that your sample is not showing

Answer (score 7):

I was able to get away with using `--jsonArray` tag, giving the file full path, and modified it adding bracket at the beginning and at the end,

```
[{"my":"json","file":"imported"},{"my":"cool","file":"succeeded"}]
```

```
mongoimport --db myCoolDb --collection myCoolColl --file /path/to/my/imported/file.json --jsonArray
```

Comment: fyi `--jsonArray` is limited to imports of 16 MB or smaller.

Answer (score 5):

The comment about non "UTF-8" characters was helpful.

It seems like there is a problem with creating json documents using textedit in Mac. I could not find these non UTF-8 characters but i created the same file using vi test.json in mac shell. I pasted the contents, saved the file and used mongoimport. It works now.

Thanks

Comment: Had the same issue - ended up creating the json document in a sublime text - error solved.

Comment: encoding UTF-8 without BOM works for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Comment: Convert your object into an array and then use **--jsonArray** and **--legacy** at the end of your mongoimport url . working fine

Comment: In TextEdit, try Format -> Make Plain Text. This goes to plain text from Rich Text, and won't mess up your formatting anymore.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error while importing json data. Instead use the .bson data using mongorestore command.

```
mongorestore -d <db> -c <collection> <.bson-file>
```

Use `--drop` if you want to drop the existing data in the collection.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting `Failed: error processing document #112783: invalid character ',' looking for beginning of value` because one of my objects was formatted improperly. Notice how "psychosurgery" is missing curly braces:

```
{
  "word": "psychosurgeons",
  "firstLetter": "p"
}
  " psychosurgery",
{
  "word": "psychosurgical",
  "firstLetter": "p"
}
```

Since there are over 600,000 lines in the file I'm trying to import, this would have been tough to find manually.

So I ran the same `mongoimport` command with full verbosity (`-vvvvv`) enabled, and the script stopped right on the problematic object. See `mongoimport --help` for more info.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem because I used texteditor on the mac. The solution was to convert the file to plain text. Make sure the extension ends in .json because texteditor wants to put .txt at the end.

Comment: Same as above, didn't help, this is how I had already saved the file.

Answer (score 0):

Just open a text file, copy all the data to the newly created text file. While saving the text file select the option 'UTF-8' in the **Encoding** drop down and later change the text file to JSON or CSV by renaming.

Then import the file as usual as it is.

Answer (score 0):

if you used mongoexport to download use mongoimport to upload
or if you use mongodump to download use mongorestore to upload
because i used to download with mongodump and tried to upload with mongoimport i was getting `error processing document #1: invalid character '\u008c'`error after i tried with mongorestore it was fine