# mongoimport fails due to invalid character in massive file, possibly an issue with the character encoding

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

When I run the following command:

```
mongoimport -v -d ntsb -c data xml_results.json --jsonArray
```

I get this error:

```
2020-07-15T22:51:41.267-0400    using write concern: &{majority false 0}
2020-07-15T22:51:41.270-0400    filesize: 68564556 bytes
2020-07-15T22:51:41.270-0400    using fields: 
2020-07-15T22:51:41.270-0400    connected to: mongodb://localhost/
2020-07-15T22:51:41.270-0400    ns: ntsb.data
2020-07-15T22:51:41.271-0400    connected to node type: standalone
2020-07-15T22:51:41.271-0400    Failed: error processing document #1: invalid character '}' looking for beginning of object key string
2020-07-15T22:51:41.271-0400    0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.
```

I have tried all the solutions in [this file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870155/mongodb-mongoimport-error-invalid-character#30873850) and nothing worked. My JSON file is 60ish MB in size so it would be really hard to go through it and find the bracket issue. I believe that it is a problem with the UTF-8 formatting maybe? I take an XML file I downloaded on the internet and convert it into JSON with a Python script. When I try the --jsonArray flag, it gives the same error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: The message says the error is with the document #1. Post the JSON for first couple of documents in your question.

Comment: Every programming language has a json parser. Use your favorite one to verify the file is syntactically valid.

Comment: @prasad_ I believe there is only one document. It is all one file and it is all one JSON object with a massive array inside. I will look and see if there is a problem with the first element of the array. How is the document defined?

Comment: @D.SM This worked well for me. I used Pythons json library to parse and it gave me several exact character numbers that were issues. I used vim to jump to that character with the pipe | symbol and I had to swap a few escape characters in Python for \\. HOWEVER, my error is now that my file size is too big for Mongo... hah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out within this massive file there were a few unnecessary commas. I was able to use Pythons built in JSON parsing to jump to lines with errors and remove them manually. As far as I can tell, the invalid character had nothing to do with the } but with the comma that caused it to expect another value before the closing bracket.

After solving this, I was still unable to import successfully because now the file was too large. The trick around this was to surround all the JSON objects with array brackets [] and use the following command: `mongoimport -v -d ntsb -c data xml_results.json --batchSize 1 --jsonArray`

After a few seconds the data imported successfully into Mongo.